# AWS CDK pipeline : how to assign a CodeBuild output to a Lambda code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I have the following AWS CDK pipeline which works. It basically takes source from 2 different GitHub repositories (one for the application code, one for the cdk code) and builds the application code and the cdk code :

```ts
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as codepipeline_actions from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline-actions';
import * as codepipeline from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline'
import * as codebuild from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-codebuild'


import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { CodePipeline, CodePipelineSource, ShellStep, CodeBuildStep } from 'aws-cdk-lib/pipelines';

export class CdkPipelineStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        // parameters
        const ConnectionArn = 'arn:aws:codestar-connections:region:account:connection/xxx-yyyy'


        // Source
        const cdkCodeStarConnection = CodePipelineSource.connection('owner/cdk-repo', 'master', {
            connectionArn: ConnectionArn
        })

        const lambdaCodeStarConnection = CodePipelineSource.connection('owner/lambda-repo', 'master', {
            connectionArn: ConnectionArn
        })

        // Building Lambda
        const lambdaBuildStep = new CodeBuildStep('BuildLambda', {
            buildEnvironment: {
                buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.AMAZON_LINUX_2_3
            },
            input: lambdaCodeStarConnection,
            commands: ['variouscommands'],
            partialBuildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject({
                phases: {
                    install: {
                        "runtime-versions": {
                            python: "3.9"
                        },
                        "commands": ["python --version"]
                    }
                }
            })
        })

        const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
            pipelineName: 'Pipeline',
            synth: new ShellStep('Synth', {
                input: cdkCodeStarConnection,
                commands: ['npm ci', 'npm run build', 'npx cdk synth', 'npx cdk ls'],
                additionalInputs: { 'lambda': lambdaBuildStep.addOutputDirectory('lambda') }
            })
        });
    }
}
```

Now, what I would like to achieve is to be able to assign the built code (so the output of the `lambdaBuildStep`) to a Lambda function I have in another stack i.e. in the code snippet below, I want `assign_output_CodeBuildStep` to be the s3 location where `lambdaBuildStep` has built my function:

```ts
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';

import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { Bucket } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3'

import {backendBuildStep} from 'cdk-pipeline-stack'; 
import {ArtifactMap} from 'aws-cdk-lib/pipelines';


export class LambdaMonolith extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
        super(scope, id);

        const s3Code = assign_output_CodeBuildStep

        const LambdaFunction = new lambda.Function(this, 'MyFunction', {
            code: lambdaCode,
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
            handler: 'lambda.handler',
          });
    }
};
```

and I can't seem to find a way to transfer that information from the pipeline stack to the Lambda stack.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `LambdaMonolith` Stack deployed as a stage in your `Pipeline` pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution. Maybe not the solution. Indeed, this seems quite convoluted ... and I am sure there is a better way.

So the solution lies in the fact that the ShellStep in the CodePipeline construct attaches the output of `additionalInputs` (so the result of the previous CodeBuildStep i.e. `lambdaBuildStep`) in a specific directory which is dynamically generated but stored in an environment variable called `CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_BuildLambda_lambda_repo` so you can see it's a combination of the name of the CodeBuildStep and the repo (with the dash changed to underscores).

So my solution was to use this environment variables as my Lambda code asset.

```tsc
        const LambdaFunction = new lambda.Function(this, 'MyFunction', {
            code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(process.env.CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_BuildLambda_lambda_repo || ""),
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
            handler: 'lambda.handler',
          });
```

Comment: Since this post has been one and a half years, I wonder if you could achieve this in a different way without using that cryptic env var.